# Reading the same stdin with two commands in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

I would like to pipe an output of  to two separate commands <2,3> in bash. What is the best way of doing this? At the moment, I have following script:

```
command source > output
command2 output &
command3 output &
```

The output file is ~100G and a suboptimal way would be to pipe to commands 2 and 3 separately. I would think it is possible to do even more efficiently.

Comment: Found out that [tee](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/144/redirect-output-to-multiple-processes/) is a possible way. Is this the way for the particular task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In bash: `command source | tee >(command2) >(command3)`

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218103/osx-linux-pipes-into-two-processes) stackoverflow question. I haven't tried this with ginormous outputs.

Comment: This command won't work unfortunately as "tee" dumps a copy of the output to a file, and another to stdout.  (And yes, I tried it just to make sure this did not work as posed above)

Comment: `tee` can take multiple files as arguments (which is how the two process substitutions appear to `tee`). You can redirect `tee`'s standard output to `/dev/null` as well.

Comment: Here's a concrete example that prints `foo` three times: `echo foo >(cat) >(cat)`. If you don't want the output, here's one that prints `foo` twice: `echo foo|tee >(cat)|cat`.

Comment: tee works but it's asynchronous, so if command 3 ends first then it will be printed first. I also had formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers introduce the concept. Here is an actual demonstration:

```
$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | tee >(md5sum > out1) >(sha1sum > out2) > out3

$ cat out1
11e001d91e4badcff8fe22aea05a7458  -

$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | md5sum
11e001d91e4badcff8fe22aea05a7458  -

$ cat out2
5ed25619ce04b421fab94f57438d6502c66851c1  -

$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | sha1sum
5ed25619ce04b421fab94f57438d6502c66851c1  -

$ cat out3
Leeroy Jenkins
```

Of course you can `> /dev/null` instead of out3.